# Не отображается модель в админке Django

Tags: python, django, сервер, регистрация, модель

Я новичок в обучении. Не могу понять, в чем проблема.

1. Cоздано приложение DjangoProject. Имеет пакеты `crm` и `DjangoProject`
2. В `crm` зарегистрирована новая модель

В models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):

    order_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    order_tel = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

3. В `DjangoProject` в settings.py приложение зарегистрировано:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'crm.apps.CrmConfig',...
```

4. База учебная. Таблица `crm_order` не пустая (объекты созданы через SQLiteStudio)
5. В admin.py выполнена регистрация модели:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Order

admin.site.register(Order)
```

6. Миграция выполнена
7. Сервер рестартовала

Тем не менее, в админке `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` модель не отображается.

Никаких видимых ошибок не наблюдаю.
Не знаю, где искать...

Comment: А что в CrmConfig?

Comment: Стоп...А это где? https://ibb.co/kMGYbWB

Comment: если речь про settings.py  то само приложение зарегистрировано тоже INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'crm.apps.CrmConfig'

Comment: Ладно, задам вопрос по-другому — что такое crm.apps.CrmConfig?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят
Это глюк матрицы
Рестарт ноутбука, несколько рестартов сервера...
Пересоздание superuser  и чудо случилось

crm.apps.CrmConfig - это в crm/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CrmConfig(AppConfig):
default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
name = 'crm'

**Спасибо за участие.**

Comment: «Пересоздание superuser»? Тогда, может быть, вы просто открывали админку от имени пользователя, который не имеет доступ к редактированию данной модели

Comment: Нет. У меня был только один пользователь

Comment: Я не знаю в чем была проблема. По факту я несколько раз рестартовала сервер. Заходила под суперпользователем (в том числе с логаут). Потом уже рестарт ноутбука. После по http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/  перестал распознаваться мой пользователь. я его снова создала и все ожило